# Trying to create Login System in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, file, authentication, readline

I'm trying to create a simple Login system for my program, however I am experiencing errors when it comes to adding more than one username and password,as the implemented error message appears when I attempt a secondary username and password, however it works with the first username and password I implemented!

e.g

> `Matthew~Dorrian` (this works if it's the first written to a file)
>
> `Dorrian~Matthew` (this does not work as it's the second written to a file)

The username and password is written to one file, which looks like:

> `Matthew~Dorrian~Dorrian~Matthew`

The username and password are written to the file as ("~" + username + "~" + password + "~")

```
string[] users File.ReadLines("users.txt").ToArray();
bool UserFound = false;



for(int i = 0; i < users.Length; i++)
{
    string[] usernameandpassword = users[i].Split("~");
    if(username == usernameandpassword[0] && password == usernameandpassword[1])
    {
        userfound = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: " when it comes to adding more than one username and password" where is the code that is "adding more than one username? what is the error message? description? does you computer fall apart when you do this? ;) is smoke coming from it?

Comment: What’s the error you’re having?

Comment: Hi, I've updated my original question to be more in depth as to what my actual problem is. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Debug this and see what really is in usernameandpassword - it is not what you think

Comment: "The username and password are written to the file as ("~" + username + "~" + password + "~")" please post this code, as this is the root of your problem

Answer (score 2):

> Matthew~Dorrian~Dorrian~Matthew

It's written in one line, and you are trying to read everything line by line

> string[] users File.ReadLines("users.txt").ToArray();

users[0] would be "Matthew~Dorrian~Dorrian~Matthew" and there are no users[1]

> for(int i = 0; i < users.Length; i++)

So this would loop only one time, and with this

> if(username == usernameandpassword[0] && password ==
>   usernameandpassword[1])

you then get only 2 word out of 4, because it only looped 1 time

Edit:
My solution would be to change this

```
if(username == usernameandpassword[0] && password == usernameandpassword[1])
{
    userfound = true;
    break;
}
```

to this

```
    int i = 0;
    while(i + 1 < usernameandpassword.Length)
    {
        if(username == usernameandpassword[i] && password == usernameandpassword[i+1])
        {
            userfound = true;
            break;
        }
        i+=2;
    }
```

Edit 2: But then, it wouldn't work if your file looked like this:

```
Matthew~Dorrian~Dorrian
Matthew
```

It would just skip second Dorrian and then second Matthew because only one left.
So here is solution that solves this:

```
int count = 0; //how many strings in buf
string[] buff = new string[2]{ "", "" }; //here we will store our results
for (int i = 0; i < users.Length; i++)
{
    string[] usernameandpassword = users[i].Split("~");
    for (int wordIndex = 0; wordIndex < usernameandpassword.Length; wordIndex++)
    {
        buff[count] = usernameandpassword[wordIndex];

        count++;
        if (count > 1)
        {
            if (username == buff[0] && password == buff[1])
            {
                userfound = true;
                break;
            }
            count = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much! Unfortunately there seems to be another error that I cannot fix.  The use of "Count++" followed by the if statement therefore results in a runtime error, as the value exceeds the index of the array. Would there be any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Per the description in your question, "The username and password is written to one file, which looks like Matthew~Dorrian~Dorrian~Matthew".

If this is how your file actually looks, I believe the issue is that you are trying to generate an array of lines with each line representing a separate user/password combination in your file, but the entirety of your data file is being stored on one line.

```
string[] users File.ReadLines("users.txt").ToArray();
```

If you just placed each user/password combination on a separate line in the file, that should take care of your issue.

I also wanted to note that if this app is for anything other than just testing or educational purposes, you should probably be encrypting the login info that you appear to be storing in plain text.

Answer (score 0):

Your source data

Matthew~Dorrian~Dorrian~Matthew

Had both users and passwords on s single line,

So when you read the file you getting one line, not two.

For this code to work you need the second user on a new line.
I.e.

Matthew~Dorrian
Dorrian~Matthew

Currently your second user is stored in 3rd and 4th element of the first line split. I.e usernameandpassword[2] and usernameandpassword[3] in the first entry to the loop.